# When does this object become eligible for garbage collection?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have this piece of code, and I am confused about when the Object o becomes eligible for garbage collection in Java.

```
    public class JustSo
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
             for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
             {
                     Object o=new Object();
                     //o.doSomething();
             }
             System.out.println("DONE");
        }
    }
```

Since it is inside  a loop(or any block for that matter), it will become eligible at the end of the loop right?

But I found an answer on a reliable developer site(Don't want to disclose where) that says the earliest the object becomes eligible is at the print statement.

Please clarify.

Comment: all objects in java become **eligible** for garbage collection when there are no more references to them. that does not mean that it will ever be garbage collected, just that it **may** be.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson no problem. just notified you.

Comment: @Suresh (anyone else) it is a dupe at least half a dozen question so you need to close it if you can now that I pasted the wrong one. Instead of spending the time to write an answer for something this basic and you know there are plenty of dupe targets vote to close it as such!

Comment: When your object is not referred and your young-generation is full, then JVM will garbage collect. JVM's garbage collection is Non-Deterministic by nature, so you cannot claim that at this point, it will be garbage collected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it becomes out of scope, so after each iteration of the for loop. An object is **eligible** for garbage collection when it is no longer reachable, this occurs in 2 situations.

- The object no longer has any references point to it.
- All references to the object have gone out of scope.

The latter is the situation for the object in question, and it the object's reference is out of scope after the for loop. Prior to the print statement.

Comment: Thank you for your clear and concise answer. I am unsure why all the answers attracted negative votes.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not saving the reference into some outer-scope variable,and creating new instance each time as soon as single iteration complete, its eligible for  garbage collection.

So when you came out of loop, all the objects created inside eligible for GC.

May be you confused with author wording here. Consider below code

```
 for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
             {
                     Object o=new Object();
                     //o.doSomething();
             } -----> objects ready for GC here. 
             // some other code  
             // some other code
             System.out.println("DONE");
```

Answer (score 1):

As the oracle documentation about the [garbagecollector](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html) says:

> Automatic garbage collection is the process of looking at heap memory, identifying which objects are in use and which are not, and deleting the unused objects. An in use object, or a referenced object, means that some part of your program still maintains a pointer to that object. An unused object, or unreferenced object, is no longer referenced by any part of your program. So the memory used by an unreferenced object can be reclaimed.

This means as soon as an `Object` isn't referenced from any other `Object` or is out of scope, it will be marked for deletion. In this case, the reference is out of scope, each time the loop starts again (just before every increment). Thus each object will be marked for deletion at the end of the loop (before the next loop-repetition).

Answer (score 0):

Each time around the loop, around the time when `i++` happens, the object will become eligible for GC.